# How to remove codes generated by plugins from Chrome browser developers tool?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

I'm using Google Chrome Developers tool and console while developing and debugging my web applications.

I've some Chrome plugins/extensions installed. These plugins/extensions add extra markups and scripts in the pages while rendering them in the browser, and when I view my codes in the developers tool, makes it a lot messy.

I want a clean way to view my codes without those extra markups.

So is there a way to toggle (disable/enable) the plugins quickly, or in the best way, to disable them in a particular tab? I've several plugins/extensions installed and I don't think it's a good idea to disable and then re-enable them manually.
Besides, I may want to use a plugin/extension while I'm browsing other websites on other tabs simultaneously.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no mechanism to disable an extension for a specific tab, or specific host. You could hack something together via the [`management` API](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/management.html) that would disable extensions when you hit a specific URL, but that disabled state would be global, not local.

Extensions don't, however, run in Incognito mode (unless you explicitly whitelist them via a checkbox at `chrome://extensions`): that might be a decent workaround for you. Load your in-development site in Incognito, work with it there in a clean environment, and pop back into your regular window for normal browsing.

You could, of course, accomplish the same thing by setting up a specific profile for development in which you simply didn't install extensions.

These are workarounds, of course. You should feel free to file a feature request for more granular user-side control over when extensions are loaded: http://new.crbug.com/

Comment: Incognito mode do serves the purpose. Thanks.

Comment: I like the profile idea (although exploiting  "incognito" would probably work 99% of the time!) For a reminder about Managing Chrome profiles see links like [this](https://superuser.com/q/805279/292784), [this](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) (remember the "user" button with your name is in the actual Window frame next to the minimize button), and [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/207614/everything-you-need-to-know-about-google-chromes-profile-switcher/)

Answer (score 1):

Would running 2 separate instances of Chrome be of help for you?

(You can start 2 unrelated Chrome browser instances from a command line specifying different user directories:  chrome --user-data-dir=userdata1 & chrome --user-data-dir=userdata2 )

I haven't tried it for your usecase, but it sounds reasonable.